# Where can I ask a question about design patterns?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to know which design patterns are used in the development of a Java project.

So where can I ask questions about this?

Comment: If your question is simply "what patterns to use" and you don't have a use case, then the question does not belong anywhere on the SE network.

Comment: If your question is "what pattern did I use here", then the question does not belong anywhere on the SE network.

Comment: As you can see, you have not provided enough information. What kind of question about design patterns is this?

Comment: @Lix presumably if it's something like Android's source, "what pattern does X use" might actually be answerable, unlike "what design pattern is my homemade server using? I think I wrote it in C or something, there were lots of semicolons."

Comment: @ben - answerable?  Perhaps... OT/NC?  Defiantly... at least for [so]...

Comment: @Oded well said in simple words you should have a "Use Case". If you dont have it then SE cant help.

Comment: I think this StackOverlow answer pretty sums it up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns-in-javas-core-libraries/2707195#2707195

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)** is the site for asking design pattern questions, however be sure your question is one that contains enough details to be answered, and is not a request for broad recommendations.

Also, I would highly recommend reading the first 3 sections of their [faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) before posting anything on that site, and be sure to look around and see if your question has already been asked before posting a question

Comment: Good advice, small thing missing: Please search the site before asking, we have a ton of [design patterns questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns), our FAQ is great but looking at similar questions is also a great way of finding out if yours fits, and you may even find an answer in the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stackoverflow itself but make few things very clear:

1. What is your actual problem statement. That means you should properly explain what you want as a result, and what are your requirements.
2. Don't be theoretical, be specific and practical.
3. Explore/Research every possible way before asking the question

So your question should be like...

> "I am working on "ABC kind of project"  and I
>   want to decide which design pattern I should prefer. I am confused
>   between the two design pattern "XYZ" and "PQR"? In my idea "XYZ"
>   design pattern would be better because it has this advantage over
>   "PQR" design pattern. But I realize that "XYZ" can give me "abc" kind
>   of problem. Is it safe to use "PQR" in my case. Anyone who have used
>   both design pattern can help me??"

Always remember stackoverflow says

*"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."*

Dont make your question chatty, make them practical (as [Oded said above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131940/where-can-i-asked-question-about-design-pattern#comment364414_131940), give a use case)

Comment: I heavily disagree...and a big -1 for using @-notification in an answer! "What should I use/What is better/What would better work"-questions are off-topic nearly *everywhere* on the SE network.

Comment: +1 for the example given

Comment: @Kobobby you going on words what i want to say is ask questions practically rather asking them theoretically. My example is a possible case. If you could give a better example, then feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: In my opinion there is no better case, because that's not a good question.

Comment: @Kobobby In my opinion its a relevant questions there are questions asked on design patterns on stackoverflow, if someone needs a better and a practical answer he can use stackoverflow.